# Flow type checking: undefined is not a function even if there is a conditional

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I am using [Flow](https://flow.org/) as a static type checker for my JavaScript code and I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot call this.props.onChange because undefined [1] is not a function.
 [1]  25│     onChange?: Time => any,
        :
     192│         if (isValid && this.props.onChange) {
     193│             const match = this.matchValue(value);
     194│             if (match) {
     195│                 this.props.onChange(this.parsedToTime(this.parseValue(match)));
     196│             }
     197│         }
     198│     }
```

My definition of Props looks like this (there are more props defined, marked with `...`):

```
type Props = {
    ...
    onChange?: Time => any,
    ...
};
```

I then use the props as a type parameter in my React class definition:

```
export default class TimeInput extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    ...

    // ...and in this class I have a method that calls onChange
    //    if onChange is not evaluated as false

    handleChange = ({ target }: { target: { value: string } }) => {
        const { value } = target;
        const isValid = this.validateInput(value);

        this.setState({
            value,
            isValid
        });

        if (isValid && this.props.onChange) {
            const match = this.matchValue(value);
            if (match) {
                this.props.onChange(this.parsedToTime(this.parseValue(match)));
            }
        }
    };
}
```

If I understand the [Flow Docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/) correctly, the `if (this.props.onChange) {...}` test should be enough for Flow to understand, that `onChange` cannot be `undefined` therefore it has to be a function (as defined in the type definition).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

up to flow docs especially ["refinement invalidation" section](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/#toc-refinement-invalidations) you should put check for `if (this.props.onChange)` right before calling.

Also I assume that specifying `defaultProps` like `onChange: () => {}` [can be a better workaround](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/#toc-using-default-props) since you get less checks before invoking callbacks.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I will look into `defaultProps`, seems quite useful.